# Вывод значений ячеек таблицы QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qmainwindow, qtablewidgetitem

В *PyQt5* в ячейки таблицы `QTableWidget` размером **`2 х 1`** записываю по порядку числа **`0`** и **`1`** и пытаюсь вывести в терминал. 
Но выводятся значения только первой ячейки: **`0`** и **`0`**.

В чем ошибка?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *    


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()            
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)

        # Задание значений ячеек                                    
        for i in range(2):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i,0, QTableWidgetItem(str(i)))

        # Вывод значений ячеек в терминал
        for i in range(2):
            print(self.tableWidget.itemAt(i, 0).text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("PyQt5")
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> QTableWidgetItem *[**QTableWidget::item(int row, int column)**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#item) const
>
> Возвращает item для данной строки и столбца, если он был установлен; в противном случае возвращает nullptr.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *    


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()            
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)
                                   
        for i in range(2):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(i)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem('33'))    

        for row in range(4):
#            print(i, self.tableWidget.itemAt(i, 0).text())
           
            item = self.tableWidget.item(row, 0)
            if item:
                print(f'строка {row}, значение колонки `0` = {self.tableWidget.item(row, 0).text()}')
            else:
                print(f'строка {row}, колонка `0` - пустая.')
            
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("PyQt5")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]